# 8086 assembly - how to access array elements within a loop

Tags: arrays, memory, assembly, x86, x86-16

Ok, to make things as simple as possible, say I have a basic loop that i want to use in order to modify some elements of an array labeled a. In the following sample code I've tried replacing all elements of a with 1, but that doesn't really work.

```
assume cs:code ,ds:data
data segment
  a db 1,2,3,4
  i db 0
data ends

code segment
start:
  mov ax,data
  mov ds,ax

  lea si,a

  the_loop:
    mov cl,i
    cmp cl,4
    jae the_end

    mov ds:si[i],1      ; this is the part that i don't really understand since
    inc i               ; i'm expecting i=0 and ds:si[i] equiv to ds:si[0] which
  loop the_loop         ; is apparently not the case here since i actually receives the
                        ; the value 1
  the_end:
    mov ax,4c00h
    int 21h
code ends
end start
```

I am aware that I could simply do this by modifying the element stored in `al` after the `lodsb` instruction, and just store that. But I would like to know if it is possible to do something like what I've tried above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In x86 assembly you can't use a value stored to a memory to address memory indirectly.

You need to read `i` into some register that can be used for memory addressing, and use that instead. You may want to check [Wikipedia for 8086 memory addressing modes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_architecture#Addressing_modes).

So, replace

```
mov ds:si[i],1
```

with (segment `ds` is unnecessary here, as it's the default of `si`, `bx` and `bx+si` too):

```
xor bx,bx
mov bl,[i]
mov [bx+si],byte 1 ; some other assemblers want byte ptr
```

There are other problems with your code too. The entire loop can be made easier and fixed this way:

```
    lea  si,a

    xor  cx,cx
    mov  cl,[i]

@fill_loop:
    mov  [si], byte 1
    inc  si
    dec  cx
    jnz  @fill_loop
```

Or, if you want to save 1 byte and use `loop` instruction.

```
 @fill_loop:
    mov  [si], byte 1
    inc  si
    loop @fill_loop
```

Note that in 16-bit mode `loop` instruction decrements `cx` and jumps to label if `cx` is not zero after decrement. However, in 32-bit mode `loop` decrements `ecx` and in 64-bit mode  (x86-64) it decrements `rcx`.

Comment: `mov bx,[i]` isn't going to assemble or work well if `i` is a byte. You got it right with `movzx`. But it may be important to know that this is a 80386+ instruction.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze You're right, so I fixed it and converted to 8088/8086 code.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that your code does not even run through the assembler, since

```
mov ds:si[i],1
```

is not a valid address mode.

Use something like

```
mov byte ptr [si],1  ; store value 1 at [SI]
inc si               ; point to next array element
```

instead (used MASM to verify the syntax).

The `DS:` prefix is unnecessary for `[si]` since this is the default.

See also [The 80x86 Addressing Modes](http://cs.smith.edu/~thiebaut/ArtOfAssembly/CH04/CH04-2.html).