# convert number byte array to string and print it- Assembly x86

Tags: arrays, assembly

In the data section, you get a byte array of numbers like:
num db -100,34,63
and its output in dos box should look like:
-100 34 63

Comment: You can get each digit of the number using the modulo/remainder with something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118490/getting-each-individual-digit-from-a-whole-integer), obviously you have to convert that to assembly (which is simple). For each digit, add 48 to convert it into a character, and  push it into an array. Check out [this](https://github.com/FISHARMNIC/asmLibs/blob/main/stdout.s#L157) method I created to print a string. It's not DOS assembly but you should be able to understand it. :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Also [8086 assembly - how to access array elements within a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14979969) for looping over an array of bytes.